# Validate address of india using regex - php

Tags: php, regex, validation, preg-match, street-address

I have some address as below

```
text #4/5, Some company & name with - in its name ltd.,
3rd cross, 5th main
(some land mark)
some place name
state, IN 566003
```

my regex below is not working

```
\d{1,5}\s\w.\s(\b\w*\b\s){1,2}\w*\.
```

for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found an answer

```
^(\w*\s*[\#\-\,\/\.\(\)\&]*)+
```

- `\w*` match any word character `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`
- `\s` match any white space character `[\r\n\t\f ]`
- `[\#\-\,\/\.\,\(\)\&]*` match a single character present `# - , . / ( ) &`
- `+` Between one and unlimited times
- `^` assert position at start of the string
- `*` Between zero and unlimited times

Comment: In java - ^(\\w*\\s*[\\#\\-\\,\\.\\/\\(\\)\\&]*)+

Answer (score 1):

use this regular expression. It may help you

```
^[0-9]+\s+([a-zA-Z]+|[a-zA-Z]+\s[a-zA-Z]+)$
```

Please try :)

Comment: can you explain me whats happening, Will this accept # , . - ( )